# How to get an int value out of textbox in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: textbox, j#

I'm a decent programmer in Java, but all my classes use eclipse so this Christmas I wanted to play around with Visual Studio so that I could build actual GUI's. So I downloaded Visual Studio 2005 cause it includes J#. Right now just trying to play around with getting values from textboxes and setting values there. 
My only problem is that the only command I can see that will return the value of the textbox is texBox1.get_Text(), which returns a String value. I want an int value though. Is this even possible from a textbox? The only methods that I saw that return ints are get_Right() and such, but i'm guessing thats for tree building.
Any help would be really appreciated, even if the answer is no. Maybe you can tell me another way I can get int values from users?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

A texbox's Text property is string, so you won't be able to get an integer directly out of that, but you could use one .net's many approaches to casting/conversions to do that. 
if you know for sure the value is an integer you can use int.Parse(); if you're not sure than use int.TryParse()

Comment: Since users are allowed to input whatever they want into a `TextBox`, it's generally advised that you use `TryParse`. Only use `Parse` if you've specifically restricted the textbox control to accept only numeric input. And even then, you can't be sure that the value entered will fit into an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to parse the string yourself, using `Int32.Parse()` or `Int32.TryParse()` like so:

```
Int32 value = Int32.Parse(texBox1.get_Text());
```

This is by the way the same way you'd do it in Java (swing, SWT).
Also J# ist a discontinued product. You should not start new projects using J#.

Comment: ok so I tried this out, and I'm being told that it can't find type "Int32". So i just tried using this:                                int x = int.TryParse(textBox1.get_Text()); and then it tells me that there is an unexpected int.